# Is there a API to know current iOS/Mac is 64bit OS or 32 bit OS?

Tags: ios, macos

Do you know any API can tell me the bitness of current OS(iOS and MacOSX)? can we assume MacOSX is 64bit?

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for code you can run in your app that tells you whether the device is 64-bit or do you want to determine the mode of the current program? Big difference because a 32-bit app can be running on a 64-bit device.

Comment: There's also the question of the mode of the kernel. It's not likely these days, but a 64-bit device may be running a 32-bit kernel which is hosting/managing 64-bit processes, etc.

Comment: I want to know the kernel bitness, not device bitness, and not program  running mode. For example, a 32bit-Windows can run on 64-bit CPU. But I do not care about the bitness of CPU, I want to know the OS/Kernel's bitness.

Comment: Keep in mind that OS X is quite different from Windows and Linux in this regard (as I mentioned above): the 32-bit OS X kernel can run 64-bit processes (on 64-bit hardware, of course). Just about the only reason to care about the bitness of the kernel is for drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can assume OS X is 64-bit based on the OS version.
(more specifically the Cocoa version.)

More importantly, you have to ask yourself what you are trying to accomplish.
In general, the Frameworks protect you from needing to think about this most of the time, especially in Objective-C land.
If you stay in Objective-C land, you can go simple with macros:
CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE (from CGGeometry.h)

NSObjCRuntime.h defines NSInteger and NSUInteger.
The macro **LP64** found there indicates 64-bit integers

https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html

In general if you try to use NSInteger, NSUInteger and CGFloat, you don't need to think about it.

If you want to know more specifically about the core C type sizes, you want to learn about the standard models created. LP64    ILP64   LLP64   ILP32   LP32
These indicate what to expect. You can't really actually assume there is one model for 64-bit.
You can have different integer and float max lengths depending on architecture.
Depending on system, you could even have an emulation of a type length.
http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html
These are defined with macros like **LP64**

You can find these in CFBase.h

But the real question is still, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610424/determine-kernel-bitness-in-mac-os-x-10-6?rq=1).                                             This may help you.

You can see which kernel you are using in System Profiler:

```
Choose About This Mac from the Apple () menu.
Click More Info. 
Select Software in the Contents pane.
Look for "64-bit Kernel and Extensions: Yes (or No)" under the System Software Overview heading.
```

These Macs use the 64-bit kernel by default in Mac OS X v10.6.

```
Mac Pro (Mid 2010)
MacBook Pro (Early 2011)
iMac (21.5-inch and 27-inch, Mid 2011)
```

These Macs use the 64-bit kernel by default in Mac OS X Server v10.6 (they can also use the 64-bit kernel in Mac OS X v10.6, but do not use it by default).

```
Xserve (Early 2008) and later
Mac Pro (Early 2008) and later
Mac mini (Mid 2010)
```

These Macs support the 64-bit kernel, but do not use it by default.

```
iMac (Early 2008) and later
MacBook Pro (Early 2008 through Mid 2010)
```

Comment: Do you have any programmatically way? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this,

   

     struct utsname un;

    int res = uname(&un);

    if (res >= 0) {

        NSLog(@"%s", un.machine);

    }

you should import the required library. 
ie `#import <sys/utsname.h>`