# C#: Is 64bit operating system cross platform (windows, unix, mac) Net 2.0

Tags: c#, operating-system, cross-platform

I want to determine via C#, using NET 2.0 framework, if my operating system is 32 bit or 64 bit.

I can't use Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem, because is only valid on net4 and above.

Y can't use native dll windows funcions or registry properties, because this is only valid for windows.

Is there any way to check this in unix and mac?

Comment: You'll have to decide how to make that check based on the runtime environment. Meaning you'll need all three implementations.

Comment: Yeah, I've got code for windows, but I can't find anything for MAC OS X and Unix

Comment: Pehaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3610928/1870803) can help?

Comment: Any reason you're stuck on .NET 2.0? Mono has supported .NET 4 for ages.

Comment: @Jon We want compatibility with old windows versions

Comment: Just how old? .NET 2.0 is really *ancient* - are you willing to support versions of Windows that even Microsoft doesn't support any more?

Comment: Yes, Windows XP included.

Comment: could you check that link?

[How to detect Windows 64-bit platform with .NET?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net

Comment: @onu301 The solutions I see there or are Windows specific, either are for NET 4, either say if it's a 64 bit or 32 bit process, but nothing about OS type :(

Answer (score 1):

Finally, that worked for Linux (Unix and Mac):

```
    static string GetLinuxArchitectureType()
    {
        Mono.Unix.Native.Utsname result;
        int res = Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.uname(out result);

        if (res < 0)
            return "N/A";

        return result.machine;
    }
```

Comment: I said I already had this code for windows, it's easy to find. I check first the OS type and use this funcion on unix and mac

Comment: To check to OS type you use http://stackoverflow.com/a/9129523/2626313  and in case of `PlatformID.Unix` you branch to this function ?

Comment: Well, I switch in case > PlatformID.WinCE (Unix, MAC and xBox, the last doesn't make sense for me)